# Book recommendation: Introduction to Traffic Flow and Traffic Models

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, mathematical-modeling

I would like to look into the subject of traffic flow and traffic modelling. I have no prior experience with this, so it should be an introduction, preferably one with a level suited for a determined undergrad.

It should contain overviews of the most popular models and their underlying concepts. 
And it would be nice if there were tie-ins with simulations and the use of non-linear DE (dynamical systems) to explain stuff like jams, and graph-theory could be an interesting use as well. 
And lastly, it should be reasonably recent, since I suspect there has been a lot of development in the field in the recent years.

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Why do you think there was a lot of development in the recent years? 2. Look at not that recent [Mathematical Models: Mechanical Vibrations, Population Dynamics, and Traffic Flow](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Models-Mechanical-Vibrations-Mathematics/dp/0898714087/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1456699075&sr=1-1&keywords=haberman+mathematical+models). It is a nice book for an undergraduate.

Comment: @Artem 1. Because computers, mostly - I'd imagine that being able to simulate things would have an impact. 2. Thanks for the recommendation!